# Choose second largest or smallest number in KDB

Tags: max, min, kdb

Is there a simple way to find the second largest or smallest number in a group of columns of a table?

I can easily find the largest or smallest by using `select min`/`max (a, b, c, d) by i from t`.

However I can't seem to figure out a simple way to find the second (or third) largest or smallest from the group.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want only second maximum/minimum, you can use:

```
       q) a: 4 3 5 1 6 8
       q) max a except max a  / second maximum
       q) min a except min a  / second minimum
```

But if you want general function that would work for any nth min/max, here is one way:

**For Nth maximum**

```
       f:a (idesc a)[n-1]   
       q) a (idesc a)[2-1]    // second maximum
```

**For Nth minimum**

```
       f: a (iasc a)[n-1]  
       q) a (iasc a)[2-1]   // second minimum
```

Comment: `iasc`/`idesc` doesn't account for ties unfortunately and OP doesn't specifically preclude ties. Take for example third largest: `6~a (idesc a:4 2 5 1 6 6 8 8)[3-1]` , correct is `5~`

Comment: Good catch. Using 'distinct'  on list before iasc/idesc will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `rank` for this:

```
q)a:10?100
q)a
65 93 15 82 76 14 75 78 44 79
q)f:{x where y=rank x}
q)f[a;1]              / second smallest
,15
q)f[a;2]              / third smallest
,44
```

I don't think there is a reverse `rank` function in q so you can do this:

```
q)f2:{x where y=iasc idesc x}
q)f2[a;1]             / second biggest
,82
q)f2[a;2]             / third biggest
,79
```

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/sort/#rank